# viewWillAppear not called on contained VC if parent is between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, swift

I recently ran into a headache with iOS view controller containment.

Everything works as expected, except in one particular case:

- If a child view controller is contained by a parent while the parent is in-between its viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear calls, then viewWillAppear will never be sent to the child VC (the child VC sees viewDidLoad and then viewDidAppear).

This edge case can come up e.g. if you create and contain a child VC as the result of an asynchronous network call, which might land in-between the parent's viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear.

I've put together a demo here: https://gist.github.com/cellularmitosis/8205610a80112eebd96c

To reproduce this locally, create a new "Single View Application" iOS project in Xcode, then replace the contents of ViewController.swift with the above gist.

Am I missing something obvious here, or is this a bug on Apple's part?

I'm guessing this means I need to override shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods() to return false, and then manually call beginAppearanceTransition and endAppearanceTransition?

Answer (score 0):

Follow-up: This is the workaround which I'm currently using: https://gist.github.com/cellularmitosis/56d734ab087a3f283455

I implemented a view controller transition state tracker, and if the parent VC is in-between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear, then we answer false to shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods.

containChildViewController is updated to handle both true and false for shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods.

Definitely a kludge, but it appears to work.

TODO: There may be an analogous bug during the viewWillDisappear -> viewDidDisappear transition.  I haven't checked.

EDIT: edited the workaround gist to use beginAppearanceTransition/endAppearanceTransition instead of directly calling viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear